# How to use applescript to control the noise canceling of AirPods Pro?

Tags: applescript

I want to implement a alfred workflow to control my AirPods Pro to switch between "Transparency Mode" and "ANC Mode". How can I write an apple script to simulate click on "audio" menu bar to switch noise-canceling. Or there is a better solution?

Comment: Hello! I know that this is not accepted. But for a long time I cannot resolve the issue. Could you help me? I would be very grateful. I can't find AirPods Pro in my area. Could you just open up my small xcode project and test it please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69851479/audio-files-wont-play-with-airpods-pro-on-ios-15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple apple script solution after trying.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "SystemUIServer"
        click (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 whose description contains "volume")
        click menu item "your AirPods name" of menu 1 of result
        click menu item "noise control mode" of menu 1 of result
    end tell
end tell
```

Change the `your AirPods name` to your AirPods name and change the `noise control mode` to which you want to (like `Off`, `Noise Cancellation`, or `Transparency`, or to your language as `关闭`,`降噪`,`通透模式` in Chinese).

---

Inspired by [anton-uspehov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11510779/anton-uspehov)'s answer. I updated the script to automatic connect AirPods when it is not connected.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "SystemUIServer"
        click (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 whose description contains "volume")
        try
            click menu item "your AirPods name" of menu 1 of result
            click menu item "noise control mode" of menu 1 of result
        on error
            key code 53
            click (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 whose description contains "bluetooth")
            click menu item "your AirPods name" of menu 1 of result
            click menu item "Connect" of menu 1 of result
        end try
    end tell
end tell
```

Or if your want to auto switch between `Noise Cancellation` and `Transparency`

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "SystemUIServer"
        click (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 whose description contains "volume")
        try
            click menu item "your AirPods name" of menu 1 of result
            if value of attribute "AXMenuItemMarkChar" of menu item "Transparency" of menu 1 of result is "✓" then
                click menu item "Noise Cancellation" of menu 1 of result
            else
                click menu item "Transparency" of menu 1 of result
            end if
        on error
            key code 53
            click (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 whose description contains "bluetooth")
            click menu item "your AirPods name" of menu 1 of result
            click menu item "Connect" of menu 1 of result
        end try
    end tell
end tell
```

---

## For macos Big Sur (10.14) users, use the following script

```
set AirPodsName to "Your AirPods name"
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "ControlCenter"
        set volMenu to menu bar item "volume" of menu bar 1
        tell volMenu to click
        set btCheckbox to checkbox 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window "ControlCenter" whose title contains AirPodsName
        set btCheckboxValue to value of btCheckbox
        tell btCheckbox to click
        delay 0.1
        set checkbox_anc to checkbox 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window "ControlCenter" whose title contains "Noise Cancellation"
        if exists checkbox_anc then
            if value of checkbox_anc is 1 then
                set checkbox_transparent to checkbox 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window "ControlCenter" whose title contains "Transparency"
                tell checkbox_transparent to click
            else
                tell checkbox_anc to click
            end if
        end if
        tell volMenu to click
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Would it be possible to get a script that works on Ventura?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, so I solved it in this way (with the error handling if the AirPods are not connected + popups):

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "SystemUIServer"
        click (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 whose description contains "volume")
        try
            click menu item "nestim AirPods Pro" of menu 1 of result
            if value of attribute "AXMenuItemMarkChar" of menu item "Transparency" of menu 1 of result is "✓" then
                click menu item "Noise Cancellation" of menu 1 of result
                display notification "Noise Cancellation active" with title "Noise control:"
                return "Noise Cancellation active"
            else
                click menu item "Transparency" of menu 1 of result
                display notification "Transparency mode active" with title "Noise control:"
                return "Transparency mode active"
            end if
        on error
            tell application "System Events"
                key code 53
                display notification "Something went wrong" with title "Noise control:" sound name "Submarine"
                return "Something went wrong"
            end tell
        end try
    end tell
end tell
```